# May I use bson.objectid.ObjectId as (primary key) id in sql?

Tags: python, mysql, bson

I am thinking if I don't use `auto id` as primary id in mysql but use other method to implement, may I replace `auto id` from `bson.objectid.ObjectId` in mysql?

According to `ObjectId` description, it's composed of:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 3-byte machine identifier
- a 2-byte process id
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

It seems it can provide unique and not duplicate key. Is it a good idea?

Comment: In general you don't want to create primary keys yourself. Doing so can often lead to race conditions. If you don't want to use an integer, your best bet is to use a UUID as @Daniel Roseman suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly could do this. One issue though is that since this can't be set by the database itself, you'll need to write some Python code to ensure it is set on save.

Since you're not using MongoDB, though, I wonder why you want to use a BSON id. Instead you might want to consider using UUID, which can indeed be set automatically by the db.

Comment: I just thinking if I design a id by myself. Is there good idea or principle what I can do?

Comment: When not using INT as primary key, UUID (128-bit) is easier to use on MySQL, but it is bigger then objectid (32-bit)